# Is there any real advantage to using nested selectors?

Tags: css, selector

if #div2 is contained within #div1 is there any real advantage to referring to that in the css stylesheet? like this:

```
#div1 {
  display:block; 
}

#div1 #div2 {
 background-color:#e0e0e0;
}
```

and then similarly. i have a table ID and then it's table headers

```
#myTable {
    width:100%;
}
#myTable #productName{
   width:75%;
}
```

Comment: Quite opposite. Browsers handle css rules from right to left.

Comment: When your using id as selector no there's not any advantage, and it's not a good practice.

Comment: What if the outer selector only exists on some pages?

Comment: @VahidND there may not be clear advantages, but there are differences, for example, a nested id defined before yours would take precedence, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only advantage is that you can be more specific, for example create a rule that applies to some element only if it placed inside another one. But in most cases, there is no reason for that, and it may hurt the performance of your css (plus it creates code duplication, in case you want to change the parent ID).

In your case the selectors are IDs, and since there can be only one element with each ID, there are even less advantages for nested selectors, and probably you don't need them.

Read [this article](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) for more deep explanations.

Comment: for 2 reasons: first is css scoring (2 IDs get higher score than one ID). second is that the nested rule will only apply if ID1 is a child element of ID2, and the non nested rule will always apply.

Answer (score 1):

As element-IDs are unique in the DOM the selected context is unambiguous in the given examples and there is no advantage whatsoever.

However, when you are working with classes  nested selectors become very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Generally its not useful to nest id selectors, but there are subtle differences, in the following, the nested rule has a higher specificity and the background will be red

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">foo</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer #inner {
    background-color: red;
}

#inner {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The rules for [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) are outline in the css spec.

That being said, classes are usually the way to go, but this can be useful for changing the styles of elements based on their container (if for some odd reason you cant/wont use classes)